# passing "this" dom element -jquerymobile, zend-

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, jquery-mobile

Well, today i am dealing with an unexpected problem!

What i am using:
zend
jquerymobile

goal: The button should keep "pressed" until the other one is pressed.

```
<div data-role='controlgroup' data-type='horizontal' data-mini='true'>
<a id='btnMap' class='ui-btn-active' href='javascript:flipViews(this)' data-role='button'>Map</a>
<a id='btnListe' href='javascript:flipViews(this)' data-role='button'>Liste</a>
</div>
```

What i get:

when i alert the object in the function it is an "object DOMWindow" object, and if i alert the objectparam.id, i get undefined.

I think i should (i want to) get the element object!

p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the JavaScript inside the `onclick` instead:

```
<a id='btnListe' href='#' onclick='flipViews(this);' data-role='button'>Liste</a>
```

Comment: Thanks you all!, all answers were usefull! this one in particular applies better to the current use.

Answer (score 0):

With your function called from the `href`, `this` is the window object.

You should bind the click handler in the external JavaScript instead:

```
$('#btnListe, #btnMap').on('click', flipViews);
```

and your `flipViews` method will use `this` within the method instead of the param you are passing in.

Don't use inline JavaScript, especially with jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

You would be better served using unobtrusive javascript for this. Rather than assigning event callbacks in the HTML, assign it using jquery's event binding API:

```
$('#btnMap').click(function(e) {

  // prevents the click from navigating page to the href attribute
  e.preventDefault();

  // call your function with "this", which jQuery scopes to the clicked element
  flipViews(this);
});
```